# Tools to detect stolen content

Tags: saas

Do you know any software or tools that can be used to detect when people are stealing content from our website?

Today we are only able the do something about the duplicate content, when we find it manually. There must be some kind of tool or service to use, to detect stolen content?

Comment: how is your website built?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a part of the project called whocopied.me where you can insert a little javascript snippet and you have a dashboard that helps you with an overview.

We created a little introduction to show it in action

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsS_2oEzPqE&t=2s

If you are using Wordpress, we created a simple plugin for you to install - no requirement of understanding HTML :-)

https://wordpress.org/plugins/whocopiedme/